# Changing tax rate (country), keeping the total price

Tags: magento-1.9, price, tax

We have the following situation:

- Product should be sold at 19 EUR (that is the price - including tax - in the catalog)
- When selling to Germany, the tax rate is 19%
- When selling to Austria the tax rate is 20%

In each cases the product should be sold at 20 EUR total

Current situation: When changing the billing address to Austria, the products becomes 19,16 EUR

So of course the sellers margin changes in case of a different tax.
(It's pretty similar to Fast Food chains in Germany selling at the same price but 19% / 7% tax depending if you take-away)
Did anybody do this already and want to share his solution / approach?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be as easy as enabling the cross-border-trade setting.

[image]